# json utf-8 encoding for android

Tags: android, json, utf-8

i have some persian(utf8) words on my database for my android app and i am using json for show database information in android app.
I have following code on Databasemanager.php:

```
function getMusics()
{
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DatabaseManager::HOST_NAME, DatabaseManager::USER_NAME, DatabaseManager::PASSWORD, DatabaseManager::DATABASE_NAME);
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM musics where active = 1 order by date desc;";
    $result = $connection->query($sqlQuery);
    $musicsArray = array();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $result->num_rows; $i++) {
            $musicsArray[$i] = $result->fetch_assoc();
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($musicsArray);
}
```

and in GetMusic.php for get json information :

```
<?php
include "DatabaseManager.php";
$databaseManager = new DatabaseManager();
$databaseManager->getMusics();
```

but i have bellow jsons on output :

```
{"id":"3","name":"???","artist":"????? ????","like_count":"1","comment_count":"0","dl_link":null,"photo":"http:\/\/192.168.88.6\/musicarea\/photos\/3.jpg","active":"1","date":"2017-08-04 00:00:00"}
```

how can i solve it ??

on output(i just use persian language at 2 last rows):[image] 
on the app:
[image]

on php my admin:
[image]

Comment: have you tried setting UTF-8 as default encoding for all MySQL connections?

Comment: show how you the data in your android app

Comment: @orvenseville Data is just like that. " ????? "

Comment: @Droidman No.can you learn me how ?

Comment: @emen try using http://de2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: may you show us the HttpUrlConnection code that you are use ?in order to pull data

Comment: @Droidman thx man it works with : mysqli_set_charset( $con, 'utf8');

Comment: @Droidman insert this on answer to i accept this

Comment: @emen glad I could help, posted this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the default client charset to UTF-8. Use `mysqli::set_charset` OR `mysqli_set_charset`.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the header that it tells the client the response is encoding with utf-8

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Where should I use this? i added in bellow of <?php in both files but didnt works...

Comment: add it before the response is firing

Comment: it should be `header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");` assuming that the strings stored in the database are actually utf-8 incoded strings, won't work otherwise

Comment: Sure, also the response should be received as utf8

Comment: @BasilBattikhi ok w8

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

```
function getMusics()
{
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DatabaseManager::HOST_NAME, DatabaseManager::USER_NAME, DatabaseManager::PASSWORD, DatabaseManager::DATABASE_NAME);
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM musics where active = 1 order by date desc;";
    $result = $connection->query($sqlQuery);
    $musicsArray = array();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $result->num_rows; $i++) {
            $musicsArray[$i] = $result->fetch_assoc();
        }
    }
   header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($musicsArray);
}
```

Comment: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($musicsArray);
??

Comment: try this one bro `json_encode($musicsArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`